# Using Map Function to Map Keys with Values

Tags: c, mapreduce

Looking at the a classic example of the Map() and Reduce() functions, I am writing a program that takes a .txt file as input, then counts the frequency of each word in the document.  I did a lot of research on both functions and found a lot of examples using Java or general pseudocode, but there is one part that I cannot get an understanding of.  This is what I have now:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void map(char *name, char *content){
        char *str = (char*)malloc((9999)*sizeof(char));
        str = content;
        char* token;
        token = strtok(str, " ,.");

        while(token)
        {
                token = strtok(NULL, " ,.");
        }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        int i =0;
        char line[9999]; //= (char*)malloc((argc)*sizeof(char));
        FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        while (fgets(line, 150, fp) != NULL)
        {
                map(argv[1], line);
        }
        fclose(fp);

return 0;        
}
```

The map function is capable of tokenizing every word in the document line by line, but the part I do not understand is how to map the values.  How would the typical "emit(token, 1)" be translated into C?

Comment: You need to read the chapter dealing with pointers and the one dealing with strings in your C text book. `char *str = (char*)malloc((9999)*sizeof(char));` followed by `str = content;` is pointless. You need `strcpy(str, content);`. But there are more issues, the `map` function looks like total nonsense to me. Please [edit]  your question ans explain what this function supposed to do.

Comment: I understand how malloc works I just put that in there for quick testing... that wasnt even related to the question I asked at all; I am asking how or where I am supposed to be mapping these values to.

Comment: If you put weird code here, you will most likely get comments like this. Very often people ask a specific question about their code, but there are actually many other problems in their code.

Comment: So is your actual question "How can I implement a map that  in C that allows me to map strings to numbers?"

Comment: Yes, I am trying to understand what emit is supposed to actually translate to in order to map the tokens to a value

Comment: This question is too unclear to be saved by an edit; the code is out of touch with the question and with what is explained/asked in the comments. I believe there should be a better, shorter and clearer way to state what is that you need with a minimum code example (one that, for example, tries to implement "reduce", and give some meaningful output of some sort, even if a toy problem)

Answer (score 0):

This would usually be solved through a dictionary of some kind (just as the java and pseudo-code examples likely used). You might, for example, use a binary search tree (likely the self-balancing red-black tree) with each node holding a word and count. An unbalanced BST is very easy to create, not so efficient to search. Another solution (easier to implement but likely much slower to run) would be to have a simple struct holding a pointer to a string and a count and have an array of such structs. This would end up requiring a great deal of copying and likely quite a lot of reallocation (and thus the poor running time) regardless of whether you keep the array sorted or not.

Comment: I have to use mapreduce